# jQuery filter or :input selector is faster than the other

Tags: jquery

Do you know which one is faster from below codes ?

**filter**

```
$("#table_po tr .th1").each( ->
    selected_obj = $(this).parents("tr")
    selected_text = $(this).text()
    $(element+' #nota_body_wrapper tr .col_po_id input').filter(->
        if selected_text is $(this).val()
            selected_obj.addClass("selected")
    )
)
```

**:input selector**

```
$("#table_po tr").each ->
    if $(element+' #nota_body_wrapper .col_po_id :input[value='+$(this).find('.th1').text()+']').length
        $(this).addClass("selected")
```

**EDIT**

TL;DR `filter` is faster than `:input`

Thanks to @A. Wolff for mentioning jsPerf.. For those of you who want to see the result check [here](http://jsperf.com/filter-or-input-selector)..

Comment: jsPerf-ing it and see

Comment: Since you are using attribute selector `value=`. I will use `filter` as it is using `$(this).val()`

Comment: The jQuery docu states that `:input` alone does not take advantage of the native DOM methods so using `.filter()` should make it faster. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/. Searching for the value together like that should take a lot more time than normal filter

Comment: The real question is: Do you *actually have* performance issues that need fixing, and have you come to the conclusion that this is the culprit? Because unless that's the case, this question is pointless.

Comment: @Tomalak not performance issue, just for the sake of knowledge.. Accidentally, I created those 2 queries, then I'm curious which one is faster..

Comment: But *why*? It doesn't make any difference whatsoever. Both are plenty fast, so fast that no user will ever notice. When it does not matter in the slightest which of two alternatives you use then it's a waste of time thinking about it.